# trying to install cabal package sdl-mpeg can't find include file smpeg.h

Tags: haskell, sdl, mpeg

running "cabal install sdl-mpeg"

```
$  ls -l /usr/include/smpeg/smpeg.h 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7503 2008-11-05 18:07 /usr/include/smpeg/smpeg.h
$ cabal install sdl-mpeg
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring SDL-mpeg-0.0.1...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing header file: smpeg.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
SDL-mpeg-0.0.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
exit: ExitFailure 1
```

I tried using --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include/smpeg and setting the same in ~/.cabal/config, but to no avail. I even tried linking smpeg.h in /usr/include.

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Comment: I'm not a Cabal expert, and I find your question interesting. On my Debian box, where smpeg.h doesn't exist, SDL-mpeg builds just fine. On the other hand, on my Arch box, where smpeg.h does exist, I run into the problem exactly the same as you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using "cabal -v3", I tracked down a solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libsmpeg-dev
cabal --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include/smpeg --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include/SDL install sdl-mpeg
```